# Magic Casting to collection of results

Tags: simple.data

In the Simple.Data examples, there is an example of 'Magic Casting':

```
// When you assign the dynamic record to a static type, any matching properties are auto-mapped.
var db = Database.Open();
Customer customer = db.Customers.FindByCustomerId(1);
```

Does Simple.Data also magically cast if there are multiple records returned? Something like this:

```
var db = Database.Open();
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = db.Customers.FindBySurname("Smith");
```

Obviously I have tried the above and it doesn't work ("Cannot implicitly convert type" from SimpleQuery to my concrete type).  Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FindBySurname returns a single record. If you use FindAllBySurname you'll get an enumerable, which should magic cast OK. (If for some reason it doesn't, you can call .Cast() on it.)